# Using group by for a SQL to filter with datetime

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012, greatest-n-per-group

I'm trying to make a sql but it is not working.

I have a table like that:

Quantity of acess  |    what computer was had the acess  |      whats date and time

```
  11                   computer 1             2013-12-30 09:00:00
  2                    computer 2             2013-12-30 10:00:00
  30                   computer 2             2013-12-30 10:11:00
  17                   computer 3             2013-12-30 17:30:00  
  200                  computer 4             2013-12-30 07:00:00
  150                  computer 1             2013-12-30 14:00:00
  19                   computer 1             2013-12-30 06:00:00
```

What I want to make is a result where it show to me only like this: in each computer, how many was the max acess and what time?  the result os SQL of the table above would be like this:

Quantity of acess  |    what computer was had the acess  |      whats date and time

```
  30                   computer 2              2013-12-30 10:11:00
  17                   computer 3              2013-12-30 17:30:00  
  200                  computer 4              2013-12-30 07:00:00
  150                  computer 1              2013-12-30 14:00:00
```

The computer 2 had max of 30 acess in exacty time 2013-12-30 10:00:00
........

the problem is how can I show the exacly date in each result?
anyone help?

thanks

Comment: You can use ROW_NUMBER for this. Post some consumable ddl and data and I will be happy to show you. sqlfiddle.com can help you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you want the date that had the most accesses for each computer?  You can use row_number in a CTE for this.
[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d6fc8/1)

```
with CTE
as 
(select
 accesses,
 computer,
 dt,
 row_number() over (partition by computer order by accesses desc) rn
 from
 table1
 )

select
* 
from
CTE
where
rn = 1
```

Comment: what if I use max in accesses? how can I group by it? I think Norm make something more like I wanted

Comment: Not sure I understand.  This will give you the row with the maximum number of accesses for each computer.  As far as I can tell, this gives the exact same result as Norm's query, just two different approaches.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it by using a sub query where you limit the values you are looking for first and then join them back to the main table.  I created a sample based on your information.  This works on SQL 2005 and allows max number of accesses returned with the specific date/time rather than combining the max number of access with the max date, which may not always be correct.

```
CREATE TABLE #Tmp(QoA INT NOT NULL, 
    Computer VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    AccDt DATETIME NOT NULL)

    Insert into #Tmp values (11,'computer 1','2013-12-30 09:00:00')
    Insert into #Tmp values (2,'computer 2','2013-12-30 10:00:00')
    Insert into #Tmp values (30,'computer 2','2013-12-30 10:11:00')
    Insert into #Tmp values (17,'computer 3','2013-12-30 17:30:00')
    Insert into #Tmp values (200,'computer 4','2013-12-30 07:00:00')
    Insert into #Tmp values (150,'computer 1','2013-12-30 14:00:00')
    Insert into #Tmp values (19,'computer 1','2013-12-30 06:00:00')

    Select * From #Tmp

    Select m.* 
    from #Tmp m
    Join (Select Max(QoA) 'QoA', Computer 
            from #Tmp
            Group by Computer) l
            on m.qoa = l.qoa and m.computer = l.computer

    Drop table #Tmp
```

Results
QoA Computer    AccDt

200 computer 4  2013-12-30 07:00:00.000

17  computer 3  2013-12-30 17:30:00.000

30  computer 2  2013-12-30 10:11:00.000

150 computer 1  2013-12-30 14:00:00.000

Comment: Yes you can do it like this but you have to hit the base table twice now instead of once.

Comment: I understand that but I also remember a time when I used Row_Number in a query only to find out that our clients were on an older version of SQL and it wouldn't run on their systems. :)  So now he has several alternate choices that can work depending on his supported SQL instance.

Comment: @SeanLange actually SQL Server often performs a "segment top" optimisation here and only hits the base table once. [here's a link](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/paul_white/archive/2010/07/28/the-segment-top-query-optimisation.aspx) and [demonstration on SQL Server 2000](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/29789/how-group-with-mindate-and-select-an-another-column-in-the-same-table/29841#29841)

Comment: @MartinSmith interesting. I did not realize that. Nice to see a link to my friend Paul White also. :)

Answer (score 2):

Like this.

```
with MySortedData as
(
    select
        ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by computer order by quantity_of_access desc) as RowNum
        , quantity_of_access
        , computer
        , datetimecolumn
    from
      mytable
)

select *
from MySortedData
where RowNum = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Its not very clear WHICH date you are looking for, but it appears you are looking for the max date, grouping by computer and finding the max results.

```
select
  max(quantity_of_access),
  computer,
  max(datetimecolumn)
from
  mytable
group by
  computer
```

Comment: The OP wants to the row with the largest quantity_of_access per computer.

Comment: @SeanLange, thanks for the tip, I didnt catch that immediately, fixed.

Comment: It isn't fixed. There is no guarantee that the two max are the same row.

Comment: That isn't quite it either. They don't want the max, the want the whole row.